# conditions in random walk algorithm

Tags: c#, random

I'm a beginner in programming and I have been assigned a mini-project. the instructor was very unclear as to what I should exactly do. All I know is that it's a "random walk" and I should not be using a method, I only have to use loops, branching and random number generators (not even sure about this one). It should also receive a number of steps from the user and walk according to the given number. 
anyways, I am a beginner with a very limited knowledge of C#. I have researched a lot, here and also in many other places, with no success. the codes are either very complex or are in other languages. 
I have written a bit of the code. I don't know if it's correct. 
please give me some pointers. 
There are no errors but the program does not work, there is a problem with the conditions.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int row = 100;
        int col = 100;
        int[,] matrix;
        matrix = new int[row, col];
        int n;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of steps:");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        const int up = 1;
        const int down = 2;
        const int left = 3;
        const int right = 4;
        int number=0;
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                matrix[i, j] = number;
        }
        Random randomdirection = new Random();
        for (int counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
        {
            int direction = randomdirection.Next(1, 5);
            while (direction == 1)
            {
                if ((++col) < 100 && matrix[row, ++col] == 0)
                {
                    matrix[row, ++col] = ++number;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            while (direction == 2)
            {
                if ((--col) < 100 && matrix[row, --col] == 0)
                {
                    matrix[row, --col] = ++number;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            while (direction == 3)
            {
                if ((--row) < 100 && matrix[--row, col] == 0)
                {
                    matrix[--row, col] = ++number;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            while (direction == 4)
            {
                if ((++row) < 100 && matrix[++row,col] == 0)
                {
                    matrix[++row,col] = ++number;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                Console.WriteLine(matrix[i, j]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This is the assignment: 
A drunkard begins walking aimlessly, starting at a lamp post. At each time step, the drunkard forgets where he or she is, and takes one step at random, either north, east, south, or west, with probability 25%. How far will the drunkard be from the lamp post after N steps? 
It's very incomplete. 
we have not been taught classes and methods so logically we should not use them. the point I think is to use arrays and loops and branching. 
I did write the code myself. that's why it's so messed up.

changed it to this: 
seems like I don't see the problem :((

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random randomObject = new Random();
        int randomDirection;
        int[,] mainarray;
        int row=10;
        int col=10;
        mainarray=new int[row,col];
        int number=0;
        for (int b=0;b<row;b++)
        {
            for (int c=0;c<col;c++)
                mainarray[b,c]=number;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            int n;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of steps: ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                randomDirection = randomObject.Next(1, 5);
                if (randomDirection == 1 && row < 0 && row < 10)
                    mainarray[++row, col] = ++number;
                if (randomDirection == 2 && row < 0 && row < 10)
                    mainarray[--row, col] = ++number;
                if (randomDirection == 3 && col < 0 && col < 10)
                    mainarray[row, ++col] = ++number;
                if (randomDirection == 4 && col < 0 && col < 10)
                    mainarray[row, --col] = ++number;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                    Console.Write(mainarray[i,j]);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You would do good to explain what you want to achieve

Comment: Where did you get this code from? You are really better off by starting yourself because I'm 100% sure you didn't write this code. What a mess...

Comment: `I should not be using a method` is it your interpretation or requirement from instructor? `there is a problem with the conditions` What is the condition, and how your `random walk` logic want to flow?

Comment: Have you considered talking to your instructor to clarify the things you don't understand, both about the language and about this particular assignment?

Comment: Programming is specific. The code will execute to do exactly as you have written the code. Everytime you run the same program, it will do the exact same things. You cannot have a vague assignment and try to code that. Make sure the goals of the program are exact. Clarify that up first. And second of all, when you have a vague assignment, don't ask us how it should be. We don't know that either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach as a whole is faulty.

Say you have a grid of 100 x 100. And you'd like to walk random directions for x number of steps. You will want something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random randomObject = new Random();
    int randomDirection;
    while (true) { //because your program needs to run infinitely
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of steps:");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //You walk a random way each step

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            randomDirection = randomObject.Next(1,5);

            if (randomDirection == 1)
            {
                //walk right
            }
            if (randomDirection == 2)
            {
                //walk left
            }
            if (randomDirection == 3)
            {
                //walk up
            }
            if (randomDirection == 4)
            {
                //walk down
            }
            //Also check if you aren't walking against walls! 
        }
     }
}
```

EDIT after your comment and edit of the question:

You can check if you walk against a wall by doing `randomDirection==1 && row<100` like you said. You have to write some code to take an other direction though, because if you can't move that way but `i` gets increased, it would be wrong. Then you wouldn't move but a step would be counted.

You can do that line of code (and with all the other directions) like you said to check if you move out of bounds. I'd change all the if's to an `else if` statement. After `else if (randomDirection == 4 && col < 100) {}`, write `else { i--; }`.

As for checking how far the drunkard has walked, you can use the Pythagorean theorem.

EDIT2: You use: `randomDirection == 1 && row < 0 && row < 10`. You are always checking if row is lower than 0. It should be `row > 0`.

EDIT3: Actually your whole use of the `mainArray` makes no sense. Why not set `row` and `col` to 0, and if you walk right, do `row++`?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random randomObject = new Random();
    int randomDirection;
    int row = 1;
    int col = 1;

    while (true)
    {
        int n;
        row = 1;
        col = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of steps: ");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            randomDirection = randomObject.Next(1, 4);
            if (randomDirection == 1 && row > 0 && row <= 10)
                row++;
            else if (randomDirection == 2 && row > 0 && row <= 10)
                row--;
            else if (randomDirection == 3 && col > 0 && col <= 10)
                col--;
            else if (randomDirection == 4 && col > 0 && col <= 10)
                col++;
            else
                i--;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You have walked in row: " + row);
        Console.WriteLine("You have walked in col: " + col);
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how to check for walking against walls.
shouldn't I have an array here? is the array I have the right thing?
the only thing that came to mind was writing something like this: 
if (randomDirection==1 && row<100)
{
   //move right
}
but this isn't right, is it?

Comment: thank you so much. the way you explained it really helped. it actually works now. thank you so much.

Comment: @rapture It's not quite correct yet and not the best way to solve this, but you should get the idea :) Good luck!

Comment: Thank :)
Yes, I got it. and also I can't believe I didn't see the "row<0" thing... :(